# Unable to connect to Cassandra db using php driver in laravel project

Tags: php, docker, cassandra

I really need some help with this, spent the last two days trying to figure it out.

I am attempting to migrate a laravel project from Mongo to Cassandra. I use docker containers for my local setup, 
here is the docker-compose.yml file with the relevant information

```
version: '2'
services:
mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: marketdata_mongodb
    environment:
    - MONGODB_DATABASE=marketdata
    - MONGODB_USER=marketdata
    - MONGODB_PASS=marketdata
    - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
    volumes:
    - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
        - 27017
    networks:
    - main_network

cassandra:
    image: cassandra
    container_name: marketdata_cassandra
    command: bash -c 'if [ -z "$$(ls -A /var/lib/cassandra/)" ] ; then sleep 0; fi && /docker-entrypoint.sh cassandra -f'
    environment:
    - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=dev_cluster
    # Cassandra ulimt recommended settings
    ulimits:
    memlock: -1
    nproc: 32768
    nofile: 100000
    volumes:
    - ./cassandra_data:/var/lib/cassandra
    ports:
    - 7000
    - 7001
    - 7199
    - 9042
    - 9160
    networks:
    - main_network

networks:
main_network:
    driver: bridge
```

After some searching on google, I found this library https://github.com/cubettech/lacassa and I have been attempting to use it within 
the project to connect to my Cassandra container but have been unable to do so.

Here are the steps I have taken so far to get this working

I installed the php Cassandra driver dependencies, using these commands

```
wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/16.04/dependencies/libuv/v1.11.0/libuv_1.11.0-1_amd64.deb
wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/16.04/dependencies/libuv/v1.11.0/libuv-dev_1.11.0-1_amd64.deb
wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/16.04/cassandra/v2.8.0/cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.8.0-1_amd64.deb
wget http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/16.04/cassandra/v2.8.0/cassandra-cpp-driver_2.8.0-1_amd64.deb

dpkg -i libuv_1.11.0-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libuv-dev_1.11.0-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver_2.8.0-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.8.0-1_amd64.deb

apt-get install libgmp-dev
pecl install cassandra
echo "extension=cassandra.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
echo "extension=cassandra.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
```

I added the service provider to the config/app file

`Cubettech\Lacassa\CassandraServiceProvider::class`

I also added a new database connection for cassandra to the config/database file

```
'cassandra' => [
    'driver' => 'Cassandra',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', 7199),
    'keyspace' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'cassandra_db'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
],
```

these are my env variables

```
DB_CONNECTION=cassandra
DB_HOST=marketdata_cassandra
DB_PORT=7199
DB_DATABASE=marketdata
DB_USERNAME=marketdata
DB_PASSWORD=marketdata
```

Based on all the documentation I have found, this should be enough to get it up and running but I keep running into this error

> No hosts available for the control connection

While trying to figure out the issue, I came across [this](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/d/msg/php-driver-user/3DMoQH1xKb8/xouqpZquCwAJ), 
which said that the issue could potentially be solved by upgrading the PHP driver/extension, so I tried a few different extensions that I found [here](http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/16.04/cassandra/), but I still have the same issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got external help figuring out the solution to this.

Host and port are actually not used in the original [lacassa](https://github.com/cubettech/lacassa) library. 
If you look at the documentation, here it says: “connects to localhost by default” - and that’s the same line used in lacassa [here](https://github.com/cubettech/lacassa/blob/cb8e24d2a005c00a6be561cd6c1d5337db69d0dd/src/Connection.php#L87)

```
$cluster = Cassandra::cluster()                 // connects to localhost by default
               ->build();
```

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/php-driver/1.3/#quick-start

A fix for this can be found in this library https://github.com/seta0909/lacassa. Alternatively, one could also fork the lacassa 
library and implement the fix on your own

Answer (score 1):

Port 7199 is the JMX monitoring port; you should change the port from 7199 => 9042.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureFireWall.html

If you are still having issues connecting to Apache Cassandra try executing the following to ensure the driver is being properly loaded via CLI:

```
php -m | grep cassandra
```

If the PHP driver module shows up then attempt to connect to the server using the driver directly:

```
<?php

$cluster = \Cassandra::cluster()->build();
$session = $cluster->connect('cassandra_db');
```

Comment: Hi @Fero, I just tried changing the port from 7199 to 9042 but I am still getting the same error message

Comment: @user3010617 I have updated the post to provide additional troubleshooting steps. I am not familiar with the Lacassa project so I won't be much help there unfortunately.